# why the following code doesn't perform as expected?

Tags: javascript, string

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="image" src="smiley.gif" width="160" height="120">

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    if (img.src == "smiley.gif")

    document.getElementById("image").src="landscape.jpg";
    else
    document.getElementById("image").src="smiley.gif";
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick = "myFunction()"> click me </button>
<p>The original image was smiley.gif, but the script changed it to landscape.jpg</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to let the HTML page to switch between two pictures each time user click the button, but the picture never changes.

When I change the

```
if (img.src == "smiley.gif")
```

into

```
if (img.src.match("smiley.gif"))
```

then the code works as expected.

Could anyone please let me know the reason?

Comment: The filename is only part of the full URL stored in `src` ... that's it. So even if you set `src` to a filename, it will store the full URL

Comment: To see the reason, add `alert(img.src)` before `if...` to see what is actually in `img.src`.

Comment: @devnull69 thanks man! I think that might be the point I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

devnull69 is right. If you set the img's source to a relative path, it's `src` attribute will still return the full URL. You need to either fully qualify the path to the image or strip the `img.src` value to just the final component (filename) and compare.

For example, you could do:

```
var imgFilename = img.src.substring(img.src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
if (imgFilename === "smiley.gif") {
    // Do something.
}
```